# Remote debugging UWP app on Windows 10 Phone device

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to remote debug application on my Windows 10 phone. Although I have developer mode ON (set in Developer mode), Device discovery ON and Device Portal also ON, I can't make debugging work:

> The Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear
>   to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall
>   is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help
>   for assistance on configuring remote debugging.

I checked firewall and other network related settings, it should be all fine. I'm using VS 2015 U3. I can access the developer portal on the IP address.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use a usb data cable to connect your phone to the pc. It's not remote debugging though. To do Remote Debugging the you must install VisualStudio Remote tools in the remote computer. So since you can't do that in a phone you must connect it through a usb cable.

Comment: Since phone has developer tools and device discovery over wifi (for debugging) is turned on, I would assume it should work even without cable. Or is it something that is not supported at all?

Comment: Yeah, at present we can only deploy apps over wifi. That also using command line tools. To debug you must connect it via a usb cable.

Answer (score -1):

If you want debug on remote computer you need install [Remote Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) on remote computer. For debug on real phone use Debug on device instead
[image]

Comment: This requires a USB connection, though. Debugging over Wi-Fi is still broken in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (see [Unable to pair Windows 10 Mobile Devices](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2127326/unable-to-pair-windows-10-mobile-devices)).

Comment: No, OP used Mobile as remote device, by now, we can only deploy an app using command lines, this is not for debugging. For debugging on mobile device, we can only connect mobile to PC using USB cable.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm asking about remote debugging, not about debugging using USB cable. I, unfortunately, need to debug something that I can't do over the cable.

Comment: @user969153: Since you cannot install the remote debugging service, nor use Visual Studio for debugging over Wi-Fi, it doesn't appear to be possible. It would probably help to understand, why you believe that debugging over USB doesn't work for you. Maybe you are trying to solve the wrong problem.